# Load dynamic jenkins shared library from pull request

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

I am trying to load Jenkins shared library dynamically, I tried below

> library identifier: 'custom-lib@pull/111/head', retriever: modernSCM(
> [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
> remote: 'git@git.mycorp.com:my-jenkins-utils.git',
> credentialsId: 'my-private-key'])

I tried few options like identifier: 'custom-lib@origin/pr/111/from' and dentifier: 'custom-lib@origin/pr/111/merge'

nothing is working, getting below error:

```
ERROR: Could not resolve pull/111/head
```

Please suggest if there is any other way

Comment: What is inside Jenkinsfile? Pull request do not exists - what _branch_ do you want to "load"? I have `library( identifier: "thelib@${env.BRANCH_NAME}",`  that works for me, could be the branch is wrong.

Comment: I suspect you followed the https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

`pull/111/head` - that is a very suspicious branch name. Anything Jenkins does you can do locally. Try to checkout that branch manually. If you cant, Jenkins will not be able to do it either.

Comment: Jenkins docs example is based upon github and I am using bitbucket thats why i was getting error. I changed syntax as per bitbucket and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by making slight change in the library identifier.
Example given on the jenkins docs https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ have example of github as I am using Bitbucket i had to below change in the library identifier to make this working.

```
library identifier: 'custom-lib@pull-requests/111/from'
```